# 100% copied articles with orginal articles

Tags: seo, google

One of my clients needs to publish around 1000+ 100% copied articles on his website. **Legally, he has already got permission from the article owner**. The purpose of these articles is, keeping the users are on the website for a long time.

He doesn't want organic traffic for this copied articles. But I said these articles can be affected to reduce organic traffic for your original articles. he asked me o find a solution for it.

How can I put 1000+ these copied articles on the website, but without negative affecting for original articles (SEO Wise)?

**Update**: I forget to mention that we don't copy full content for our pages for some pages... For example, if there is a 3000-word post, we might copy most useful 1000 words. Still is it ok to add "canonical" tag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a rel Canonical to avoid Duplicate content errors on Google.

For each article on your client's web site add a meta in head with the url of the origin article.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/article-url" />
```

For the official source, you can check this page :

https://moz.com/learn/seo/duplicate-content

About your update, this definition given by Google makes clear if you copy 1000 words of 3000 without rewriting it, this will be Duplicate content.

> Duplicate content generally refers to substantive blocks of content within or
>   across domains that either completely match other content or are
>   appreciably similar.

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66359?hl=en

The only way you have not to make DC is to rewrite those articles or add a Canonical. So, Yes it's still ok to add Canonical tag ;)

**An easier way** could be to add a `no-index` meta tag on your pages this way you are sure your copyed articles don't harm original ones SEO.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and I accept it. I have just one question. As I know, when we add a canonical there is no need to add no-index since canonical pages are not indexed. Is it wrong?

Comment: You're Right and moreover, Google doesn't understand well when canonical & noindex are mixed in the same page https://www.seroundtable.com/google-noindex-rel-canonical-confusion-26079.html

Answer (score 2):

Articles that are duplicate/syndicated are supposed to have a "canonical" tag added to their header to point to the original file.

Normally this would be done on a file level, but you might consider using .htaccess to do instead.  Htaccess supports regular expressions and pattern matches to identify files.  This could potentially save you from having to edit every article individually.  See this [article](https://www.danielmorell.com/guides/htaccess-seo/crawling-indexing/put-rel-canonical-on-non-html-resources) for detailed instructions.